# Minus sign in analyzing RC with changing emf circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, conventions

I'm learning electromagnetism from Purcell's book.
He say that if we have the following circuit:

[image]

$$-\frac QC + RI = \mathcal E_0\cos\omega t~,\quad I = -\frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dt} $$

The equations are as written.
I have two questions:

1. Why is there minus sign in the current equation? I understand the charge on the capacitor is getting lower thus the current is reducing with time.
   Is this some physicist way of telling it?  If I was to come from a math point of view, lets say that the function $Q(t)$ is the charge in time on capacitor. Then it would have negative $\mathrm dQ/\mathrm dt$ by itself, and we do not need the minus sign. Is adding minus works when we do not know the function $Q(t)$ and want to say that the current is decreasing?
2. Why is there a minus sign in the Kirchoff's second law equation?
   Can we have a minus near $RI$ instead of $Q/C$?

Comment: Think it for an _infinitesimal_ moment; the charge in the capacitor is decreasing; that is $\mathrm dQ$ is negative; however, current is increasing; that's why the '$-$' sign.

Comment: $Q$ is the charge on the lower plate, that's why there is a minus sign in both equations.

Comment: VIP - this is not the case. Q can be anywhere on the capacitor.
My lecturer has said it is a physicist convention of saying that the charge is decreasing on the capasitor and I is decreasing as well. That's why minus.
MAFIA - curent is not always increasing. it increases to a certain point and then starts to decrease again.

Comment: @EvanOst: Of course, it does not increase at all the times; after all it is a harmonic function. The basic notion is to create a differential equation considering an infinitesimal moment of what is happening - presently, it is the capacitor is discharging and current is increasing. Now, when you _integrate_ the differential equation, it would yield the __general__ solution, independent of what infinitesimal moment you considered to create the differential equation.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 So lets analyze it step by step.
Stage 1 -  current increases to a certain point and the capacitor get discharged meanwhile.
Stage2 -  current decreases and charge on capacitor drops also until current is really low and capacitor almost discharged.
Stage 3 -  increase in I in opposite direction and capacitor is getting charge.
Stage 4 - decrease in I and Capacitor getting charge.
The current increase/decrease is not always correlates inversely to charge decrease/increase.
Why integrating would yield a general solution? Which ODE are you talking about?
Thanks for the advice

Comment: Again, I would say: concentrate on the scenario in an infinitesimal time-interval; assemble them in a differential equation; solve it and you would get your answer. Take any __one__ of the scenario you have mentioned above; make the differential equation and solve it; the solution would be valid for all those other stages including the one you used.